# Vue custom event handling with watchers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to show some proxy text while the ajax call is running. Additionally when the call is completed, I want to hide the text. So I have coded two components, one is AppBody which will hold a button for simulating an ajax call in its slot. The other is DownloadBtn in which the execute method will perform the ajax call. Before and after the ajax call, I changed the value of a variable called loaderStatus and watch that variable for change. Whenever the variable got changed, it emitted custom event called download. After receiving the event from child component DownloadBtn, AppBody component acknowledged this event inside doSomething method of vue instance and another variable called loadSpinner gets changed. I bind this loadSpinner variable to AppBody props, so whenever this loadSpinner gets changed the text value should appear/hide accordingly. But the problem is the text appears but do not hide as expected. However, if I remove the props then console log returns the expected output but I do not have the text as the text depended on that props value. Any help would be highly appreciated. fiddle link : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yoh0L76j/8/)

I have a js code snippet like this:

```
Vue.component("app-body", {
    template : 
  `
   <div> 
      <div v-if="loader">
         <p>Please Wait Ajax Call is Running</p>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
         <slot></slot>
      </div>
   </div>
  `,
  data () {
    return {}
  },
  props : {
    loader : Boolean,
  }
});

Vue.component("download-btn", {
    template : `
    <div >
        <button type="button"  @click="execute"> Download </button>
    </div>
  `,
  data () {
    return {
        loaderStatus : false,
    }
  },
  props : {

  },
  methods : {
    execute () {
        //ajax call
        this.loaderStatus = true;
        console.log("Starting ajax call");

        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
            this.loaderStatus = false;
            console.log("ajax call completed")
            /* this.$emit("download", true); */
        }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
    }
  },
  watch : {
    loaderStatus() {
        console.log("in watch::loaderStatus=>"+ this.loaderStatus);
        this.$emit("download", this.loaderStatus);
    }
  } 
});


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   loadSpinner : false
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething(newLoadSpinnerValue) {
        console.log("in doSomething::newLoadSpinnerValue=>" + newLoadSpinnerValue);
        this.loadSpinner = newLoadSpinnerValue;
    }
  },

})
```

and html portion is like this :

```
<div id="app">


 <app-body :loader=loadSpinner>
     <download-btn @download="doSomething"></download-btn>
   </app-body>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like a pretty complex solution to a simple problem, you really only need to communicate between 2 components, there is no need to involve your `app` and use slots, simply pass from the button to the `app-body` a `loader` prop and that should solve your issue.

Comment: @Michael Should I pass button to appbody a prop ? or emit event ? button tab is child component of AppBody here. Can you share a fiddle ?

Comment: I would make a loader component then give it as props `loading` from the parent which would be the component making the api calls. See here for an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682506/vuejs-vue-spinner
The spinner there is custom but you can just make your own loader (then you can reuse anywhere in the app or other apps)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `slot` is only mounted when the loading is not in progress. When loading starts the `slot` is removed which means the loader component will be unmounted and anything that happens in it will not run any watchers or events. The value will never be reported back and the slot never reactivated.

You will need to handle the hiding of the download button somehow differently if you want to have the downloading to happen inside the button.

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dag4mvn5/1/) where the child is not removed when loading, properties work correctly.